# Let $G$ be a Graph with $n$ vertices then the Chromatic number is greater or equal to its clique number.

Tags: graph-theory

I am new in this field and I was trying to understand about clique and chromatic number. Please help me to show this relation. 
Well I know that: relation can be written like this: $$\chi(G)\geq\omega(G)$$ where
$\chi(G)$ is the Chromatic number and
$\omega(G)$ is the Clique number.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the symbols; your question isn't too symbol-heavy anyways (you could even have compromised and written "x(G) >= w(G)" for better readability). For next time, you can use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write symbols and equations.

Answer (score 1):

In a colouring of the graph, every clique must consist of differently coloured vertices. This especially holds for the largest clique.